# How to create Text Links on iphone 

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to create links similar to the facebook feed.  For example, when you touch down on the name of the person in the fb app on iphone, a gray rectangular box indicates it is highlighted.  Should I use a custom button for this(normal button has a border)?  What's the best approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UITextView *infoTextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 54, 300, 211)];
[infoTextView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[infoTextView setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0]];
[infoTextView setText:[dict valueForKey:@"desc"]];
infoTextView.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
infoTextView.layer.borderWidth = 1;
infoTextView.clipsToBounds = YES;
[self addSubview:infoTextView];
[infoTextView release];
```

Comment: you need to use custom button where the images will be changing for the required state. Have an image which has border for the custom btn